# Consumer does not fetch new records from topic and always pointing to the same offset position each time it starts up

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

I am using `spring-kafka`  `2.3.7`

**Problem 1:** Two consumers (`KafkaListeners`) are in the system. When the application starts one of the `Consumers` *always* points to same `Topic/Partition/OffSet(s)`. This
might be due to consumer re-balancing.

**Problem 2:** After `(1)` the same `Consumer` is also not being able to consume any new `Message` that is sent to the `Topic`

**LOG:**

```
[tConsumer-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  [                                    ] : [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=enrollmentConsumer] Setting offset for partition bev3_enrollment_sync_topic_dev-1 to the committed offset 
FetchPosition{offset=79, offsetEpoch=Optional.empty, currentLeader=LeaderAndEpoch{leader=b-1.cpsdmskclustertestenv.7hij1q.c2.kafka.us-east-2.amazonaws.com:9094 (id: 1 rack: use2-az1), epoch=3}}

[tConsumer-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  [                                    ] : [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=enrollmentConsumer] Setting offset for partition bev3_enrollment_sync_topic_dev-0 to the committed offset 
FetchPosition{offset=73, offsetEpoch=Optional.empty, currentLeader=LeaderAndEpoch{leader=b-2.cpsdmskclustertestenv.7hij1q.c2.kafka.us-east-2.amazonaws.com:9094 (id: 2 rack: use2-az2), epoch=3}}
```

However after changing the `group-id` it is solved. But i am curious to know how can the older `Offset(s)` be committed with the older `group-id`. I am using `STCH`, `ACKMODE.MANUAL_IMMEDIATE` and `offset->LATEST`Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Set the assignment commit container property to NEVER

```
    /**
     * Set the assignment commit option. Default
     * {@link AssignmentCommitOption#LATEST_ONLY_NO_TX}.
     * @param assignmentCommitOption the option.
     * @since 2.3.6
     */
    public void setAssignmentCommitOption(AssignmentCommitOption assignmentCommitOption) {
```

By default, the container commits the current position during assignment if the auto offset reset is `latest`.

Comment: Thanks Gary. I have set ```AssignmentCommitOption``` to ```NEVER```. Still the `Topic` with the **older** ```group-id``` is not being able to receive any new ``Record``. It works when i use a **newer** `group-id`.
``factory.getContainerProperties.setAssignmentCommitOption(AssignmentCommitOption.NEVER)``

Comment: Right; you should use the command-line tool `consumer-groups` to delete the retained offset. `$ kafka-consumer-groups --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --delete --group xxx
Deletion of requested consumer groups ('xxx') was successful.`